# Can't install pyarrow - module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'

Tags: python, pip, conda, pyarrow

I'm trying to install pyarrow but it repeatedly gives me this error:

> module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'compat'

I have tried several workarounds including:

1. ! conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow --y
2. Upgrading numpy to version 1.18.1 (the latest version)
3. Upgrading pandas to version 1.0.1 (the latest version)

Yet I'm still getting this error.

Comment: please post the full error you are getting, not just one line.

Comment: This can happen when mixing pip/conda and defaults/conda-forge also I think

Comment: All fixed, the issue was that there was a conflict between my awscli version and botocore/boto3 versions. This is what worked for me:
! pip3 install awscli==1.16.1 --user
! pip3 install botocore==1.11.1 --user
! pip3 install boto3==1.8.1 --user

Comment: Note this was using Amazon Sagemaker